# How to write a string interpreter that will execute a series of turtle movement commands in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter

I am working on a project where I want to take in a string such as "F100<30S30"

F100 would move  the turtle forward by 100, <30 would rotate the turtle 30 degrees, and S30 would draw a circle with the radius of 30.

I can get the program to interpret one command, for example F100, but I cannot get it to interpret a long string as shown above. What ways can I go about interpreting this. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
Search for "parsing input Python", and you'll get appropriate tutorials to move you along.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kinds of commands your turtle can take, so this example may not exactly fit your use case. But from what I can see, you could use regular expressions to solve this problem.

Let's say a command consists of two parts: a character to indicate the operation (`F`, `<`, `S`, etc.), and a number to indicate the magnitude (`100`, `30`, etc.). Your string has several of these back-to-back. What we can do is build a regular expression that will recognize all instances of this operation-number pattern in your string.

Using only the commands `F`, `<`, and `S`, the following regular expression will work:

```
regex = r'([FS<]\d+)'
```

Let's unpack this.

- First, `r'...'` designates this string as a "raw string", which is what we typically use for regular expressions. This means characters within the string that would normally be escape characters, like `\`, will not be treated as such.
- Next, the parentheses `()` mark whatever's inside of them as a regex *match* - meaning that, when we pass through the string, anything matching the pattern inside the parentheses will be saved and outputted.
- Inside the parentheses, the square brackets `[]` denote a group of characters - this will match any character contained inside the brackets. So, in this case, the regex will look for a `F`, `S`, or `<`.
- After looking for that character, we look for a number. `\d` is a shorthand for `[0123456789]` - that is, it matches any digit.
- `+` is a sign we attach to `\d`. This tells the regex to be "greedy", which means to include as many digits as possible instead of just one.

You can now use python's `re` library to find all matches in the string. The `findall` method is what we need here: it takes one regex string and one search string, and returns, in order, a list of patterns from the search string that match the regex string.

```
>>> import re
>>> search = 'F100<30S30'
>>> regex = r'([FS<]\d+)'
>>> commands = re.findall(regex, search)
>>> print(commands)
['F100', '<30', 'S30']
```

Now, you've turned that one string into a list (`commands`) of smaller strings, each of which represents one command. You can now iterate through `commands` and execute each command individually.

For more information on regular expressions in python, you can look to [the `re` module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).